# Radvd sending advertisement to the wrong interface

Tags: networking, ipv6, radvd

I have the following radvd.conf file:

```
interface eth0
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        MinRtrAdvInterval 30;
        MaxRtrAdvInterval 100;
        route 2000:e000:0:2::/64
        {
                AdvRoutePreference low;
        };
};

interface tap_tap
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        MinRtrAdvInterval 30;
        MaxRtrAdvInterval 100;
        prefix 2000:e000:0:2::/64
        {
                AdvOnLink on;
                AdvAutonomous on;
                AdvRouterAddr on;
        };

        route 2000:e000:0:1::/64
        {
                AdvRouteLifetime infinity;
                AdvRoutePreference high;
        };

};
```

The idea is to have a eth0 interface facing an internal network and a tap interface which will have people connected from VPNs. On the eth0 interface I want to advertise routes so everyone in the internal network can see the VPN clients, the problem is that the eth0 advertisement gets picked up by other interfaces such as eth1 and that messes up the whole routing:

```
# radvd configuration generated by radvdump 1.9.2
# based on Router Advertisement from fe80::b076:c0ff:fe83:d38a
# received by interface eth1
#

interface eth1
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
        AdvManagedFlag off;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag off;
        AdvReachableTime 0;
        AdvRetransTimer 0;
        AdvCurHopLimit 64;
        AdvDefaultLifetime 300;
        AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
        AdvDefaultPreference medium;
        AdvSourceLLAddress on;

        route 2000:e000:0:2::/64
        {
                AdvRoutePreference low;
                AdvRouteLifetime 300;
        }; # End of route definition

}; # End of interface definition
#
# radvd configuration generated by radvdump 1.9.2
# based on Router Advertisement from fe80::b076:c0ff:fe83:d38a
# received by interface eth0
#

interface eth0
{
        AdvSendAdvert on;
        # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
        AdvManagedFlag off;
        AdvOtherConfigFlag off;
        AdvReachableTime 0;
        AdvRetransTimer 0;
        AdvCurHopLimit 64;
        AdvDefaultLifetime 300;
        AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
        AdvDefaultPreference medium;
        AdvSourceLLAddress on;

        route 2000:e000:0:2::/64
        {
                AdvRoutePreference low;
                AdvRouteLifetime 300;
        }; # End of route definition

}; # End of interface definition
```

The weird thing is that I've succesfully used this exact same setup in some environments, for some reason in some environments this happens out of nowhere, is there anything that I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any bridging between interfaces?